# JavaScript just won't loop through an object (geojson) in script but does so in console even though the object is loaded

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, gis, geojson

I know that that might be because the data wasn't loaded because of ajax calls which I am indeed using, but it is loaded because I can log the data before going to the parts where I iterate over the object.

This is a very peculiar behavior with the data that I have because Chrome and Firefox work in slightly different ways.

When I load the geojson file from an ajax call, the `key` starts from seemingly random values - in Chrome it started from 56 and in Firefox it started from 81. That aside, I can loop through the data when I copy paste the particular loop in console and it extracts the `latitude` and `longitude`, but it just doesn't work at all in the script itself.

What is actually happening in the [index](https://github.com/armsp/fictional-garbanzo/blob/master/index.html) file is that I load geojson from a file. Then to make a *polyline* or *linestring* I iterate through the geojson to extract `latitude` and `longitude` and push them into an array that is then passed to the internal `polyline` function of [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) to connect all the points by drawing a line.

#### Current Output

```
inside the function 
PathCoords = 
Over
```

And we don't see the points connected by lines in the map.

#### Expected Output

```
Array [ 80.14653749, 13.03620529 ]
Array [ 80.1465604, 13.03633957 ]
Array [ 80.14625642, 13.03650074 ]
Array [ 80.14640196, 13.03667878 ]
Array [ 80.1465044, 13.0368217 ]
Array [ 80.14660705, 13.03689514 ]
Array [ 80.1465697, 13.03702323 ]
Array [ 80.14660424, 13.03724193 ]
Array [ 80.14647597, 13.03741167 ]
Array [ 80.14645969, 13.03757399 ]
Array [ 80.14642552, 13.03775751 ]
Array [ 80.14646913, 13.03794248 ]
Array [ 80.14653564, 13.03804439 ]
Array [ 80.14655821, 13.03819883 ]
Array [ 80.14655482, 13.03835368 ]
Array [ 80.14649189, 13.03849665 ]
Array [ 80.14649999, 13.03862578 ]
Array [ 80.14653824, 13.03876863 ]
```

The above shows when executing the following in console -

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check._layers)){
    var x = value._latlng.lng;
    var y = value._latlng.lat;
    console.log([x, y]);
}
```

Cleaned up `index.html` (get the geojson file from the [repo](https://github.com/armsp/fictional-garbanzo)) -

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map = L.map('map').setView([13.03, 80.16], 15);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox/light-v9'
        }).addTo(map);

        var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("gps-logger-android-data.geojson");
        geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

        var check;

        function connectDots(data) {
            console.log("inside the function");

            check = data;
            var c = [];
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check._layers)) {
                console.log("Key = " + key, "--", "Value = " + value);
                var x = value._latlng.lng;
                var y = value._latlng.lat;
                c.push([x, y]);
            }
            return c;
        }
        pathCoords = connectDots(geojsonLayer);
        console.log("PathCoords = " + pathCoords);
        L.polyline(pathCoords).addTo(map);
        console.log("Over");
    </script>

</body>
```

**NOTE:**
Clone the [repo](https://github.com/armsp/fictional-garbanzo), then use `python3 -m http.server` to render the `index.html`, otherwise you'd get a CORS error while loading the geojson using ajax.

**P.S** If you could explain why the keys are different in Chrome and Firefox, that would be great.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. The script is trying to use the result before it has been received.

Comment: See https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax for how to run code when the data has been loaded.